# Is there a converse for the Primary Decomposition Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In Linear Algebra given a linear operator $T: V \rightarrow  V$, with minimal polynomial $m(x)=p_1(x)p_2(x)...p_n(x)$ and the factors $p_i(x)$ prime among themselves, $V=Ker(p_1) \oplus Ker(p_2) \oplus ... \oplus Ker(p_n) $. Also $Ker(p_i)$ is T-invariant and have minimal polynomial $p_i(x)$. Now, is it true that if a linear space can be decomposed as direct sume of T-invariant subspaces, the minimal polynomial of T is the product of minimal polynomials of the restrictions of T in each subspace? And are the minimal polynomial of the restriction prime among themselves? If those are true, can you give me a proof?

Comment: This document seems to outline an argument: https://people.bath.ac.uk/gt223/MA20012/lec15.pdf

Comment: The correct term in English for “prime among themselves” is “pairwise relatively prime”.

Answer (score 1):

Both assertions are false :

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator with minimal polynomial $\mu(x)$. Then the minimal polynomial of $T\oplus T :V\oplus V\to V \oplus V$ and the minimal polynomials of its two restrictions are equal to $\mu(x) $.

Now, the first assertion can be adapted somewhat. If $T:V\to V$ is a linear operator, and $V$ admits a decomposition into $T$-invariant subspaces, let $\mu_1(x), \ldots, \mu_n(x)$ be the minimal polynomials of the restrictions of $T$ to said subspaces. Then, the minimal polynomial $\mu(x)$ of $T$ is the least common multiple of $\mu_1(x) ,\ldots,\mu_n(x) $.

*If* the $\mu_1(x) ,\ldots,\mu_n(x) $ are prime (pairwise), then $\mu(x) = \mu_1(x) \ldots\mu_n(x) $.

Comment: But the sum of V and V is not direct, unless V=0, what's trivial.

Comment: This is an "external" direct sum, meaning a direct sum of two distinct copies of $V$. This is a different way to write $V\times V$.